# How to connect samza to other systems and how to write systemFactory class

Tags: apache-samza

Using below configuration I am able to connect samza to kafka-broker

```
systems.kafka.samza.factory=org.apache.samza.system.kafka.KafkaSystemFactory
systems.kafka.samza.msg.serde=json
systems.kafka.consumer.zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181/
systems.kafka.producer.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
```

But I'm have some doubts regarding SystemFactory class. How to write our own systemfactory class? and what is the purpose of SystemFactoryClass? please give me some idea

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own system factory class by extending the `SystemFactory` interface and implementing its three abstract functions, `getConsumer`, `getProducer`, and `getAdmin`. In each one of the functions, take `getConsumer` as an example, you want to create a system customer, an instance of another customized class extending `SystemConsumer` and defining how the system should consume. By doing so, your Samza job would know how to get the `admin/consumer/producer` of the system when needed.

Example (in Scala):

```
class YourSystemFactory extends SystemFactory {
  override def getConsumer(systemName: String, config: Config, registry: MetricsRegistry): SystemConsumer = {
    new YourSystemConsumer(
      getAdmin(systemName, config).asInstanceOf[YourSystemAdmin],
      config.get("someParam"))
  }

  override def getAdmin(systemName: String, config: Config): SystemAdmin = {
    new YourSystemAdmin(
      config.get("someParam"),
      config.get("someOtherParam"))
    )
  }

  override def getProducer(systemName: String, config: Config, registry: MetricsRegistry): SystemProducer = {
    new YourSystemProducer(
      getAdmin(systemName, config).asInstanceOf[YourSystemAdmin],
      config.get("someParam"))
  }
}
```

In your config:

```
# Your system params
systems.your.samza.factory=your.package.YourSystemFactory
systems.your.consumer.param=value
systems.your.producer.param=value
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need implement your KafkaSystemFactory. You have just implement StreamTask

Example :

```
public class MyTaskClass implements StreamTask {

  public void process(IncomingMessageEnvelope envelope, MessageCollector collector, TaskCoordinator coordinator) {
  // process message
  }
}
```

Config :

```
# This is the class above, which Samza will instantiate when the job is run
task.class=com.example.samza.MyTaskClass

# Define a system called "kafka" (you can give it any name, and you can define
# multiple systems if you want to process messages from different sources)
systems.kafka.samza.factory=org.apache.samza.system.kafka.KafkaSystemFactory

# The job consumes a topic called "PageViewEvent" from the "kafka" system
task.inputs=kafka.PageViewEvent

# Define a serializer/deserializer called "json" which parses JSON messages
serializers.registry.json.class=org.apache.samza.serializers.JsonSerdeFactory

# Use the "json" serializer for messages in the "PageViewEvent" topic
systems.kafka.streams.PageViewEvent.samza.msg.serde=json
```

For more info : [Documentation](https://samza.apache.org/learn/documentation/0.10/jobs/configuration.html)